# Distinguish HTTP and onCall Trigger of cloud functions by Google Cloud API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm planning to call all cloud function periodically from a function. Current functions are implemented by using http, pubsub, firestore, analytics, onCall trigger.

In my investigation, projects.locations.functions API on Cloud API is good for list all function.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#HttpsTrigger

But this API cannot distinguish http trigger and onCall trigger function. Both function(http and onCall) is recognized as http trigger function by the API.

Is there any way to distinguish both trigger?

Comment: Or, you could deploy another function that lists out everything you need from all the other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specification of Cloud API, so we cannot distinguish http and onCall trigger by the API.
I throw feature request to support team.